# IOS error with external object/proxy object

Tags: ios, proxy

I'm trying to make a button in my view. It executes a code that lives in other controller, so I dragged an External Object from library into my dock, then I've changed the class in the Identity inspector so it's matches my external class, but I get an error when I try to execute the app: "Missing proxy for identifier Test", even if I don't connect the button to the IBAction at my external class, just the fact of drag the External Object into my dock, and set the class already gives me this problem. Could you help me? Thanks in advance!